# diffraction of light with 1 slit, width change

Tags: waves, diffraction

does the diffraction of light with 1 slit always increases when the width length decreases?

it makes sense to me that this happens with sound waves, but i am not sure about electromagnetic waves.

thanks for the attention

Comment: Why should there be a difference in the way sound waves or EM waves spread?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it happen in EM waves? Haven’t you heard of diffraction of light?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you really, but I think you are looking for following - 
Consider you have a point light source in front of a circular aperture of diameter d. When diameter of aperture is quite larger ( ~1 cm) then you can see a patch of light on the screen with well defined boundaries. If size of aperture is decreased then at first size of aperture starts decreasing. But when size of aperture becomes very small (<0.1 mm) then pattern obtained on screen ceases to have well defined boundaries. This is what we call diffraction. 
Diffraction effects become smaller with decrease in wavelength and in the limit of wavelength 工-> 0 ( i.e. wavelength tending to zero.), the diffraction effects will be abscent, and even for extremely small diameters of the aperture you will obtain a well defined shadow on the screen. And that shadow in the case when wavelength tends to zero is called a ray of light.